# reCAPTCHA widget on Smartphone gets cut off

Tags: recaptcha, smartphone

I tested my new website's contact form with reCAPTCHA on my smartphone and noticed that the widget where you choose the correct images, gets cut off.
In the pictures you can see what I mean:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23212201/recaptcha_screenshot_1.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23212201/recaptcha_screenshot_2.png

In both, normal and landscape, the browser is already scrolled down as much as possible.

How can I fix that?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

I found out that it must have something to do with the "gc-bubbleDefault"-class which automatically sets its margin-top.

And when I use Firebug to set its margin-top to "0px", it kind of solves the problem.

BUT as it seems there is no way to set the margin-top value of the "gc-bubbleDefault"-class via css or js.

ANYWAY, another approach could be to put the checkbox to the top of the window like here:
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23212201/recaptcha_screenshot_3.png (Copy Link in URL)

But ONLY when the widget table is visible. And this raises the question:
Is there a way to check via JavaScript if the table with the class "gc-bubbleDefault" is currently visible?
(Happens when reCaptcha isn't sure if user is a robot or not and displays a bunch of pictures from which the user has to choose e.g. all the flowers.)